# SQL Datawarehouse Cube, how to allow users to create their own calculations in Excel?

Tags: sql, excel, ssas, data-warehouse

I have a SQL Server 2008 Data Warehouse Cube (SSAS), we are trying to push this to replace our "flat file extracts" that we currently use.

When our users connected to our SSAS Server using Excel they get the PivotTable, is there a way to allow the users to create their own calculated members from Excel? Some users want to make their own calculations that are not pre-defined in SQL Server...

Is this possible? Or must all calculated members be predefined on the Cube's calculations tab?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand this part of your problem statement...

> I have a SQL Server 2008 Data Warehouse Cube (SSAS), we are trying to
>   push this to replace our "flat file extracts" that we currently use.

...but for adding calculated members in excel, check [this out](http://olappivottableextend.codeplex.com/).  I believe the functionality (to add calculated members) is native to Excel (2007+), but this add-in should has a few other bells/whistles that should prove useful if your users are savvy enough to be needing this type of functionality in the first place.